# Groups object upserting return INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY exception

Tags: soap-api, exception, standard-objects

I use Salesforce SOAP API and try to upsert Groups.
I just get data from Salesforce:

```
"LastModifiedDate" -> "2018-04-15T11:35:25.000Z"
"SystemModstamp" -> "2018-04-15T11:35:25.000Z"
"DoesIncludeBosses" -> "true"
"Type" -> "RoleAndSubordinates"
"DeveloperName" -> "Test"
"DoesSendEmailToMembers" -> "false"
"Id" -> "00G58000000Y2teEAC"
"Email" -> ""
"LastModifiedById" -> "00558000000SBAGAA4"
"CreatedDate" -> "2018-04-15T11:35:25.000Z"
"CreatedById" -> "00558000000SBAGAA4"
"Name" -> ""
"RelatedId" -> "00E58000000VoaPEAS"
"OwnerId" -> "00D58000000J4I8EAK"
```

But when I try to insert it, Salesforce response `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY  insufficient access rights on cross-reference id` Exception. I removed all system and not updateable fields, such as LastModifiedId, LastModifiedDate. I also tried to remove ownerId and RelatedId from request. But it still response this error.
Id of current user is equal to `CreatedById` and organization id is equal to `OwnerId`. One of the UesrRole Id is equal to `RelatedId`. This UserRole is not related to any User.
Why this error is happend and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing OwnerId from above Group record.

Comment: It does not help. Even I try to upsert data only with `Id` and `DoesIncludeBosses`